# Hide a field from New & Edit list forms is not working on the site level, only working on the list level

Tags: development, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this PnP Power shell to hide 2 fields from the New & Edit forms:-

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://****sharepoint.com/sites/c1"
$ListName = "CustomTest"
$FieldName =  "LinkToFile"
$FieldName2 =  "LastRequested"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Get the Field
$Field = Get-PnPField | Where {$_.Title -eq $FieldName}
$Field2 = Get-PnPField | Where {$_.Title -eq $FieldName2}
 
#Hide the field from New Form
$Field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Field.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$Field2.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Field2.SetShowInEditForm($false)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

now in the above script I am trying to set the `SetShowInNewForm` & `SetShowInEditForm` at site level and get the effect on all the lists.. but the above script will not have any effect, the only way i found to fix this, is to set this on the list level as follow:-

```
$Field = Get-PnPField -List $ListName | Where {$_.Title -eq $FieldName}
```

but my question is how I can set this at the site level, so it will get propagated to all lists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to update field according to your script and you should use `UpdateAndPushChanges` (which will update site column along with list columns where ever this column is added in the site) method instead of `Update` (which will only update site column) method. Try below code, it should work:

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://****sharepoint.com/sites/c1"
$ListName = "CustomTest"
$FieldName =  "LinkToFile"
$FieldName2 =  "LastRequested"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Get the Field
$Field = Get-PnPField | Where {$_.Title -eq $FieldName}
$Field2 = Get-PnPField | Where {$_.Title -eq $FieldName2}
 
#Hide the field from New Form
$Field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Field.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$Field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
$Field2.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$Field2.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$Field2.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: you are correct, thanks